# Testing negative boundary at UI or unit level

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, selenium

I am currently trying to test an input textbox on my .NET MVC Application.

The business logic is that this textbox shall only accept numbers from range 0-120. The numbers shall not accept characters or symbols.

In my JS on the View it handles this so characters or symbols will never be posted off to the server side.

Hence in the server side I have not built any validation. This number is only used for simple division and will always be a division by 12 (so I did not test for division by 0 as it just wont happen).

Questions is where should I do my test for negative or invalid boundary (and euivalence) i.e. -1, 0, 1, 60, 119, 120, 121?

I am currently doing this test in Selenium at UI level.

This makes me wonder what should I test in the unit level on the server side?

I currently have one test that simply tests if it has done the correct division by 12 (i.e. x/12), which seems quite tedious.

Comment: Validating forms with JS is user-friendly, but not secure; you're not protecting against bad input from malicious users or clients which happen not to run scripts. As far as unit testing server code, that's probably beyond the scope of a Selenium test suite.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Should I be building this validation into the server side on the controller when I receive a post action? By unit level I meant by using NUnit test to test calculations, and one of the first thing this class does is it convert this number (0-120) by dividing by 12. Do I need to test this division?

Comment: Yeah, that'd generally be where it goes. Very few programs reach 100% test coverage, but it's up to you if that's possible or important. It's probably more important to test your input sanitization and whatever you're doing with the resulting data. Past that, I would just try to have a good idea what happens if your program gets requests outside of your expectations... what happens if I send "-200", "8137", or "foobarbaz" in a forged post?

Comment: Any reason why you won't create a custom ASP.NET MVC Validator and enable that in both server and client? You Validation logic can be Unit tested in the server. You still can use Selenium at UI level test to verify the acceptance behavior.